# How to find y at given point (x,z) on 3D triangle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

In a coordinate system where y is up/down, z is forward/backwards, x is left/right (as in Unity3D).

---

(Here's a bad drawing of what I mean)

y
|
|***_*__**_x
\
z

(z would be going into/out of your monitor I guess)

---

Given coordinate (x,z) that is guaranteed to be on this triangle, how would I get y?  Assume that you know the (x,y,z) coordinates of all three triangle points, as well as the normal of the face.  The triangle may be slanted on any axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, given any Vector `v` inside your triangle, and your normal `n`, we know that the dot product of `n` and `v` equals 0 (true for all points on the triangle).  So:

`nx * vx + ny * vy + nz * vz = 0`

Little algebra to solve for `vy` and we have:

`vy = -((nz * vz) + (nx * vx)) / ny`

One thing though.  `v` must be in the plane of your triangle, so you will need to put that vector in the plane of your triangle, by subtracting one of your vertices (say `t1`) from `v`.

So:

`vx = t1x - x, vz = t1z - z, and vy = t1y - y`

And therefore, your final y coordinate is: `y = t1y - vy` where `vy` is defined above.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by Vector inside the triangle?  Would that be the (x,z) coordinate, the (x,y,z) coordinate, or a vector as in a direction?

I understand the basic concepts, but I'm not the most up to date with my math terms.  You lost me at the t1 part.  Why would I subtract one of the vertices from v?  Could you explain it to me as if I was a large child?

Comment: `t1` is *any* of the three vertices of your triangle.  `v` needs to be a vector orthogonal to your normal so that the dot product will be zero.  You already have `t1`, `x`, `z`, and your normal: `n`.  Substituting your values into the equations above will give you your desired `y`.

Comment: Subtracting `{x, y, z}` from `t1` makes sure that the resulting vector, `v` is orthogonal to your normal.